# SSL Works in backend but not working in frontend, prestashop 1.7.04

Tags: prestashop

7.04

Very strange issue which I have been dealing with since 2 days ago but no success. My ssl certificate works perfectly in Backend but it doesn't redirect in front-end. Even my other website which is a Jooma website works fine when activating ssl.

I have added redirecting directive into .htaccess. I use plesk v17 on Ubuntu server 16.04. I use prestashop 1.7.04. my website is www.indeedz.com ... Check for yourself.

I have of course enabled the USE SSL on prestashop admin/general....

What can be the possible reasons to this? Thanks for help

Comment: Are all external files are https?

Answer (score 2):

In order to enable SSL on every page of PrestaShop .htaccess rules are not enough, you have to enable SSL from configurations as well.

In PrestaShop 1.7 you can find the configurations at following path in your admin panel:

Configure -> Shop Parameters -> General

[image]

Make sure that you have enabled the `Enable SSL on all pages` configuration.